# My if statement ALWAYS returns true, no matter what

Tags: java, if-statement

This just is't making sense to me at all.

This is my code:

```
boolean that = false;
        if (that == true);
        {
            System.out.println("That is " + that);
        }
```

And yet it will print the line even though my output is

```
That is false
```

I'm doing this in java and I'm using Eclipse galileo, so each time I compile/run my program it saves it so the compiler should be getting updated version of my program.
What's going on?

Comment: if (that == true); :) remove ; one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common mistake. Remove the `;` at the end of the `if` statement.

BTW I always write the following if I use brackets and I use the code formatter of the IDE.

```
    if (that == true) {
        System.out.println("That is " + that);
    }
```

This means if you have a mis-placed `;` or `{` it can be more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the semicolon you have here:

```
 if (that == true);
```

Remove that semicolon ! It causes the code to do nothing after checking the conditional `(that == true)` - technically it's an "empty statement"  - i.e. we can have a loop like so:

```
    for (int i = 0; ; i++){
      System.out.println("Thanks" );
    }
```

And it would go forever!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ;

```
boolean that = false;
     if (that == true)
     {
         System.out.println("That is " + that);
     }
```

otherwise the print is always executed.

Comment: I love you, can't believe I didn't realize this -.-

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
    boolean that = false;
    if (that)
    {
        System.out.println("That is " + that);
    }
```

Notice the extra semi-colon after the `if` in your code?  That's why.

The logical test is closed by the semi-colon, then the next block is always executed.

If you remove the semi-colon it'll match your intuition.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (that == true);
              // ^ The extra colon you dont need
```